# forcing to Not to process an event

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

C# WinApps:  the main form has a key binding to CTRL-V ...so anywhere in the main app when I press CTRL-V something runs..good ... but also there are some MDI apps that are opening inside this main app ... in one of those there is a test box...ah! now CTRL-V also has a meanining for text box which is "Paste" ... so I added PreViewKeyDown to textbox and handled it, so now it is pasting BUT it is ALSO doing the main CTRL-V key binding that I had defined for the whole app ... but I do no want this to happen.... what can I do?  ( I cannot change the key binding od the main app. I must keep it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register for the [Control.KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event and mark it as handled to prevent further propagation of the event.

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: so for the Preview KeyDown of that TextBox I also added a line to say inTextBox = True and then in KeyDown I am checking if inTextBox is true then e.Handled = True ... BUT it did Not fix it

Comment: @BDotA The event should propagate out, so if you are the closest control swallowing the event will not allow it to make its way to the application anyways